# Is there a priority for supporting a custom network in Gnosis Safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've observed that certain networks like [B Goerli](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/pull/111) are supported quickly in all directions, while others such as [Consilience Ventures Chains](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues/46) are not.

Could you explain the reasons behind this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Safe team, the project's progress is contingent on the custom chain team's work rate. It is essential for the custom chain to be bug-free.